# How to show only file name when searching subdirectories in bash

Tags: bash, unix, find, filenames, subdirectory

I'm trying to list all files, except hidden ones, in only the subdirectories of a folder in bash by doing:

```
$ find ./public -mindepth 3 -type f -not -path '*/\.*'
```

That returns:

```
./public/mobile/images/image1.jpg
./public/mobile/images/image2.png
./public/mobile/images/image3.jpg
./public/mobile/javascripts/java1.js
./public/mobile/javascripts/java2.js
./public/mobile/javascripts/java3.js
./public/mobile/stylesheets/main.css
./public/mobile/views/doc1.html
./public/mobile/views/doc2.html
./public/mobile/views/doc3.html
```

How can I ignore the file path and show only the file name with the extension?

Thank you :)

Comment: This should help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627446/find-and-basename-not-playing-nicely

You could use search here or google :)

Comment: Thanks! Solved :) I've been like half hour searching something like that but didn't succeed...Next time I'll be more insistent!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to only get file name with linux \`find\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456120/how-to-only-get-file-name-with-linux-find)

Answer (score 1):

Use `-printf` additionally to the `find` command, instead of `-print`.

```
find ./public -mindepth 3 -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -printf %f\\n
```

Note the usage of `\\n` - you need `\n` to add a new line after file name, but add another `\` as escape or add some quotes to prevent interpreting `\n` by shell

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can skip using `find` and using a file pattern instead.

```
shopt -s globstar    # For **
printf "%s\n" public/*/*/**/*.*
```

If you expect some files to have no extension, you'll need to use a loop and filter out
non-file matches manually.

```
for f in */*/*/**/*; do
    [[ -f $f ]] || continue
    printf "%s\n" "${f##*/}"
done
```