# Using basename to name output file in java

Tags: java, find, xslt-1.0, filenames, zsh

I have a recursive structure of directories containing some `foo` files that I want to convert to `bar` files using a XSLT 1.0 stylesheet. I have:

```
dir
|-- subdir
|   |-- file1.foo
|   |-- file2.foo
|   |-- file3.foo
```

And I want to obtain:

```
dir
|-- subdir
|   |-- file1.foo
|   |-- file1.bar
|   |-- file2.foo
|   |-- file2.bar
|   |-- file3.foo
|   |-- file3.bar
```

To capture the basename of files without the extension, I have tried:

```
$ find . -type f -exec java -jar C:/saxon6-5-5/saxon.jar -o $(basename {} .foo).bar {} stylesheet.xsl \;
```

and

```
$ find . -type f -exec java -jar C:/saxon6-5-5/saxon.jar -o `basename {} .foo`.bar {} stylesheet.xsl \;
```

Both with identical result:

```
dir
|-- subdir
|   |-- file1.foo
|   |-- file1.foo.bar
|   |-- file2.foo
|   |-- file2.foo.bar
|   |-- file3.foo
|   |-- file3.foo.bar
```

It seems the basename command is not working. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627446/find-and-basename-not-playing-nicely

Comment: Thanks, Jayan. I had seen that page. I understand you are proposing to use `-exec sh -c` in my one liner. However, I don't know how I can combine `sh -c` with `java -jar`.

Comment: Without looking at the question in detail, I would suggest [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), which is exceptionally good at this sort of tasks.

Comment: Thank you, 4ae1e1. Indeed, it seems Parallel could help, indirectly. I'm working on Windows, so I'll have to find a port or switch to Linux for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a zsh approach, since it's tagged it as such.

`for f in **/*.foo(.); print -- java ... -o $f:r.bar $f`

Remove the `print --` when you're satisfied that it looks good.

The `(.)` says files only. The `:r` says remove the `.foo` extension. It's helpful to remember the path manipulators as "erth" for extension/remove/tail/head.

There's also `zmv` with the `-p` option to call your java command.

Comment: It seems to work, thank you. I haven't tried in other shells but I understand it might only work in zsh. For the record, my code is `for f in **/*.foo(.); java -jar C:/Apps/saxon6-5-5/saxon.jar -o $f:r.bar $f stylesheet.xsl`.